# Is it possible to connect to a database using a .PF file programatically

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I would like to use a switch case for connect to different sets of databases, is it possible to use the connect statement with a .pf file that only contains -db parameters? I have tried it but I always get error 1402: parameter -p is not a database parameter and was ignored. But there is no -p parameter in my .pf files...

Something like this:

```
CASE Db_Name:
    WHEN "Test":
      CONNECT TO 'test.pf'.
    END.
    OTHERWISE:
      CONNECT TO 'Db.pf'.
    END.
END CASE.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be quite helpful to see what is in your .pf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"TO" is not part of the syntax for CONNECT.  Your CASE syntax is also wrong.

Try this:

```
case dbName:

  when "sports" then
    connect value( "-pf sports.pf" ).
  when "sports2000" then
    connect value( "-pf sports2000.pf" ).

end.
```

or, more simply:

```
connect value( substitute( "-pf  &1.pf", dbName )).
```